# Meteor MongoHQ issue

Tags: meteor, mongohq

I'm getting **Error: Could not locate any valid servers in initial seed list** when I try to connect to MongoHQ (compose.io). I'm running Release 0.6.6.2 of meteor. I tried to update to the latest version but I'm told *This project is at the latest release which is compatible with your current package constraints*.

I've set the MONGO_URL through **export MONGO_URL=TheUrl**. I even sent a support ticket to the guys at compose who confirm theUrl looks good and that server is up and running. The project was working fine with the local mongodb before I switched to compose.io. Any ideas?

Comment: Highly recommend that you update your meteor to 0.9.4 first... 0.6.6.2 is much much out of date. It seems that you are using some legacy packages. Probably take a look at your packages first.

Comment: Okay, I started fresh with a new install of meteor 0.9.4 and tried connecting with it. I am still getting the same error. I have double checked the mongo url and it looks fine. Anyone??

Comment: Can you access your compose.io database by command-line tool successfully? Did you append the username and passowrd?

Comment: No, can't connect through mongo cli with -u and -p set : `errno:61 Connection refused`.

Comment: Sorry guys! This is looking like a firewall issue. I didn't think it was because I was not connecting on the server either but that turned out to be a different issue.

Comment: congrat for figuring out the main reason for you problem